# INSERT INTO table VALUES - mysql_query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

trying to insert values from an old mysql_query using the new PDO and can't seem to get it. Here's the old code that works with the old method:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES ('','$title',time(),'0','$length','','$name','$cat','$reciter','$genre')");
```

I've tried variations of the following code taken from another question on stack, but nothing that works for me.

```
$query = "UPDATE people 
         SET price=?, 
             contact=?, 
             fname=?, 
             lname=? 
          WHERE id=? AND 
                username=?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $price);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $contact);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $id);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $username);    
$stmt->execute();
```

the first value to be inserted is an auto increment value in the db. I am at a loss as to how to write that with the new PDO. Then the third is an attempt at a timestamp. All others are values that exist in the script already.

So this is more along the lines of what I'm looking for.. Its what I have now, but doesn't work.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO videos (id, title, timestamp, views, length, image, vid_url, cetegory, reciter, genre)
                    VALUES (:id, :title, :timestamp, :views, :length, :image, :vid_url, :category, :reciter, :genre)";

$query = $DBH->prepare($sql); 
$results = $query->execute(array(
    ":id" => '',
    ":title" => $title,
    ":timestamp" => time(),
    ":views" => '0',
    ":length" => $length,
    ":image" => '',
    ":vid_url" => $name,
    ":category" => $cat,
    ":reciter" => $reciter,
    ":genre" => $genre
));
```

Comment: So is the `UPDATE` your actual code, or is it an example of what you are wanting to change to?

Comment: @Guage  To insert values you've got to use an `INSERT` statement. I think I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: the UPDATE bit is an example that I am referring to.. I don't know how to write the INSERT bit so that's why i used the UPDATE as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If id is an autoincrement, don't pass it to your query. If you specify a value to be inserted to an autoincrement table, sql will attempt to insert that value. so don't include it in the query, let SQL do that.

Secondly, if the third field is a timestamp, set the default to

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

SQL will update the timestamp automatically on update or insert (if you only want it on insert just put `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. then you also can drop that row.

You can also drop the images row if you aren't inserting anything there either, no point to put something in the query if you're not using it!

Also, the key PDO looks for doesn't have the colon (`:`) so if your item is `:title`, the array key will be just `'title'`. So, your code should look something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO videos ( title, views, length,, vid_url, cetegory, reciter, genre)
                    VALUES (:title, :views, :length, :vid_url, :category, :reciter, :genre)";

$query = $DBH->prepare($sql); 
$results = $query->execute(array(
    "title" => $title,
    "views" => '0',
    "length" => $length,
    "vid_url" => $name,
    "category" => $cat,
    "reciter" => $reciter,
    "genre" => $genre
));
```